# Property of a totally ordered Field

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory, order-theory

One of the properties of a totally ordered Field $K$ is

For all $ x , y , u , v \in ( K , > )$, then:
$$x < y \wedge u < v \rightarrow x + u < y + v$$

I'm not sure what the above property is true because it is $y \wedge u $ that is greater than $x$ and smaller than $y$ but not $y$ and $u$ itself. How do we come to the implication? Are $ x, y, u, v$ sets within $K$ ?because the definition does not specify their algebraic structure.

Last but not least, since $y$ and $u$ are not specified, can this be true?
$$x < y \wedge u < v \rightarrow x + v < y + u$$

Comment: $x<y $ and $u < v$ implies $x+u<y+u<y+v$

Comment: $x,y, u,$ and $v$ are elements of $K;$  $\land$ means "and"

Answer (score 2):

I think you are reading the statement wrong. It says:

$$(x < y) \wedge (u < v) \rightarrow x + u < y + v$$

Comment: $1<2$ and $ 5<7,$ but it's not true that $1+7<2+5$

Comment: ohhh now that makes sense ;)